# All attempts to keep readline at the bottom of the screen result in the input clearing

Tags: node.js, readline

I am currently trying to have an input kept at the bottom of the screen so that I can keep a log at the top while also allowing commands. All solutions I've found online work, but the issue is whenever I log using winston (and a custom transport), the readline prompt clears, but is kept to the bottom. It's not REALLY cleared, it just clears the visuals of it. As in, if you are typing "abc", but after you type "a" there's a new log, and you continue typing, the prompt will only show "> bc", but when you press enter the program correctly recognizes the line as "abc".

Here's what I'm dealing with right now.

```
//console.js

const readline = require("readline");

module.exports = () => {
  const cli = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
  const logger = require("./logger.js")(cli);
  cli.setPrompt("> ", 2);
  cli.on("line", (line) => {
    logger.info(line);
    cli.prompt();
  });
  cli.prompt();

  return logger;
};


//logger.js

const winston = require("winston");

class ConsoleTransport extends require("winston-transport") {
  log(info, callback){
    setImmediate(() => { this.emit('logged', info); });

    this.cli.output.write('\x1b[2K\r');
    console.log(info.message);
    this.cli._refreshLine();

    callback();
  }
}

module.exports = (cli) => {
  let consoleTransport = new ConsoleTransport();
  consoleTransport.cli = cli;

  return winston.createLogger({
    format: winston.format.combine(
      winston.format.colorize(),
      winston.format.simple()
    ),

    transports: [
      consoleTransport
    ]
  });
};
```